# Using R.String in an editText in android

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext

I have all my strings for my project stores in the string.xml file. I have no problem using them in most cases but for some reason it outputs an integer value to the editText when I mix Strings with an integer for example if I do:

```
editText.setText(R.string.x_plays + j)
```

which I want to display "X Plays: 3" to the GUI however it displays a large integer to the GUI. If I do this without j (which is an integer) it is fine.

```
editText.setText(R.string.x_plays)
```

This just displays the string "X Plays: ".

So the problem is obviously trying to concatenate  an integer with an R.string but I don't know how to work around this. I have tried using stringBuilder and adding in empty strings ("") around the R.string and integer but similar results are returned. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because `R.string.x_plays` is actually an integer resource ID that certain methods are able to convert into a string that can be displayed. One of these is setText. However, if you add a number to this ID, it may no longer be valid.

The easiest solution is to just write `getString(R.string.x_plays) + j`.

You could also change the string to a format string, such as `X plays: %1$d` and  instead write `getString(R.string.x_plays, j)`

See: [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: It does not recognize the getString(R.string.x_plays) method. I am using android studio and it does not even ask me to import

Comment: If you're in an activity, getString() should work; otherwise you need to obtain a context object, for example `getActivity().getString()` in a Fragment

Answer (score 1):

Use [getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) instead. Since you want to concatenate the String, get the String and concatenate:

```
getString(R.string.blah);
```

Actually `R.string.something` is an integer (a reference).

`editText.setText(int)`also takes this `int` value as a parameter. You can also send string as a param to `setText`. But first you would have to get the string in string.xml as string using getString() function.

Comment: It does not recognize a getString() method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use string format argument for cases when you want to join a static string (from string.xml) with your dynamic values (like i);

in Strings.xml

```
<string name="jump_message">I jumped from %1$d storey building</string>
```

in code

```
int i = 99;
String finalMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.jump_message), i);
//finalMessage becomes 'I jumped from 99 storey building'
```

Comment: I think it's more concise to pass the format arguments directly to getString—e.g. `getString(R.string.jump_message, i)`. Not sure why the Android docs don't mention this...